# semantic-ui-react List onClick declaration

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

i'm trying to create a list of documents dynamically with semantic-ui-react. I'd like to get the document title back when the list item is clicked. According to the documentation:
https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/list

there is an `onItemClick` prop for this reason, however when im using it i get a warning when it's rendered:

Warning: Failed prop type: Prop `onItemClick` in `List` conflicts with props: `children`. They cannot be defined together, choose one or the other.

Also clicking on the list item does nothing (atm i just want to log the doc title to the console). Here is the code:

```
handleListItemClick(event, data) {
  console.log("list item clicked: " + data.value);
}


buildResultsContainer() {
    return this.props.listOfResults.map((document,index) =>
      {
        return (
            <List.Item
              as='a'
              key={index}>
                <Icon name='file' />
                <List.Content>
                  <List.Header>{document.properties.title}</List.Header>
                  <List.Description>
                    {document.properties.description}
                  </List.Description>
                </List.Content>
            </List.Item>
      );
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <List onItemClick={this.handleListItemClick}>
          {this.buildResultsContainer()}
        </List>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

**Can you please tell me how to use properly the onItemClick prop for the List component?**

Less important, do you have any tip how to refactor the list rendering? Just wanted to keep the render function short and clean, but this function call looks a bit overkill....

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think maybe the intent when using `onItemClick` is that you would use the `items` prop on `List` since then you wouldn't have any `children` e.g.

```
render() {
    const items = this.props.listOfResults.map(document => {
      return {
        icon: 'file',
        content: document.properties.title,
        description: document.properties.description,
        onClick: e => console.log(document.title)
      }
    });

    return <List items={items} />
  }
```

If you had your `listOfResults` prop in the above format, you wouldn't even need to do this `map` and your `render` function would be super tight:

```
render() {
  return <List items={this.props.listOfResults} />;
}
```

Alternately, `List.Item` takes an `onClick` prop that you could define in your `buildResultsContainer()` function. Because each `onClick` function is unique based on the current `document` object, you will need to use an anonymous function to call your `handleClick` function as follows:

```
<List.Item
  onClick={() => this.handleClick(document.title)}
  ...etc
/>
```

You would then have:

```
handleClick = docTitle => {
  console.log(docTitle);
};
```

If what you wanted was obtainable from `event.target`, you could just pass the reference of `handleClick` to the `onClick` i.e.

```
handleClick = event => {
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
};

<List.Item
  onClick={this.handleClick}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried so far the alternate idea: if i give an `onClick` for the `List.item` , the function is called immediately when the list is rendered. Which is kinda strange.

Comment: `<List.Item onClick={e => console.log(document.title)} />` ?

Comment: In this case it works well. Strange (at least to my current reactjs knowledge) why `onClick={this.handleListItemClick(document.properties.title)}` gives different result.

Comment: because what you are passing there is function invocation, as opposed to reference to the function. I will add an example

Comment: Makes complete sense, it explains also why it was called during rendering in my attempt. Both of your suggestions worked flawlessly, thanks a lot!

Comment: However im still puzzled why doesn’t my original idea work (example for solution):
https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/xEmzGg?editors=0010

this snippet is from the official react docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Both, my original and your suggestion can be found on this page. I read it back and forth, but still don’t get why the example works and mine not. Is it because if there is a need to pass an argument to the function and using the `()` after function name interpreted as function call instead of reference?

Comment: @inspiral the first example is from vanilla HTML as opposed to React JSX

Comment: This is the one i was referring to: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/xEmzGg?editors=0010

Comment: That is also passing just a function reference, `this.handleClick`; it is not invoking it with `()`